# FullCalender is not working on Google Cloud Environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I am working on ASP.net core MVC 2.1 project,I am using fullcalender latest version

The problem that I am experiencing is that, when I deploy my project on google cloud environment the fullcalender is not working. But when I am running the project local, the calendar is working fine.

```
<environment include="Development">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-      easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js' asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js'    asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/lib/moment.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/FullCalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" asp-append-version="true">   </script>
<script src="~/js/FullCalendar/gcal.min.js" asp-append-version="true"> </script>
</environment>
```

These are the files that am calling on the `layout.cshtml`, worse part when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, it doesn't show me any error message related to the issue.

Comment: What error or warning messages do you get from the Developer Console?

Comment: fullCalendar runs in the browser so it's unlikely the server environment would play much of a role...unless perhaps the JS files are not loading correctly. Check your browser's console and network tools for any possible problems. The code above on its own doesn't indicate anything either way.

Answer (score 1):

It may be wrong initialization of your javascript.

Can you check the JS CDN

```
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Also check the css file

```
<link href='../fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
```

Hope this may fix your issue.